# avoid unnecessary KVO update for dependent key

Tags: objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

I have a Core Data entity that I want to store a CGRect value. Because there is no CGRect support for Core Data so I just split it into four float attributes: x, y, width, height.

In order to make it more convenient for me, I add a custom property `frame` that return the combined CGRect from the four float attributes. BTW, I am using mogenerator.

```
@interface ViewableData : _ViewableData

@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;

@end

@implementation ViewableData

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (frame.origin.x != self.xValue)
        self.xValue = frame.origin.x;
    if (frame.origin.y != self.yValue)
        self.yValue = frame.origin.y;
    if (frame.size.width != self.widthValue)
        self.widthValue = frame.size.width;
    if (frame.size.height != self.heightValue)
        self.heightValue = frame.size.height;
}

- (CGRect)frame {
    return CGRectMake(self.xValue, self.yValue, self.widthValue, self.heightValue);
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFrame {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:ViewableDataAttributes.height, ViewableDataAttributes.width, ViewableDataAttributes.x, ViewableDataAttributes.y, nil];
}

@end
```

It works as I expected but I found that KVO observer get notified too many times than it needs. Set a frame may notifier the observer 4 times. Is anyway to avoid the unnecessary KVO update notification?

---

**Edit**

Looks Transformable type is a good solution, but I still want to know a proper way to update depend key path. Another example is haveinga property `fullName` that depend on `firstName` and `lastName`. Still, if I change `fullName` I only expect the observer only get notified once instead of twice (once with `firstName` changed and once with `lastName` changed). Another problem is that at the first notification, the state is inconsistent because only partially update is performed.

I think my original example is not good enough. How about this:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString fullName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString firstName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString lastName;    

@end

@implementation Person
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;

- (void)setFullName:(NSString *)fullName {
    NSArray *names = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    self.firstName = names[0];
    self.lastName = names[1];
}

- (CGRect)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFrame {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"firstName", @"lastName", nil];
}

@end
```

Then if i do

```
person = // get Person object
person.firstName = @"A";
person.lastName = @"B";
// person.fullName is now "A B"

person.fullName = @"C D";
```

On the last line, the observer will see fist name updated (with full name of "C B", but such full name does not exist at all, which may crash my app) than last name updated ("C D")

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [A Non-Object Attribute](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW14) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" for an example how to store an `NSRect` in Core Data. Modifying this code for `CGRect` should be possible.

Comment: Make your field Transformable type, then use NSValue.

Comment: Hey, why dont you use string form of CGRect using NSStringFromCGRect, that way you could observe for just one property and make your design simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question... imho you need to think it more carefully. What if you have an observer on firstName only and you update fullName? Do you want that the observer is notified or not?

BTW: I think that you should use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` and `primitiveValueForKey:` and manually fire the notifications..

E.g.

```
- (void)setFullName:(NSString *)fullName {
    NSArray *names = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"fullName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:names[0] forKey:@"firstName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:names[1] forKey:@"lastName"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"fullName"];
}
```

In this way you fire only the notification for fullName, but not for firstName and lastName

EDIT: ok.. regarding your first question (CGRect), if you don't want to use a transformable (even if this is one of their common use) and you can "enforce" that the modification to the rect is made as a whole (that is you never call xValue, etc.. directl, you can write your setFrame as:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"frame"];
    if (frame.origin.x != self.xValue)
        [self setPrimitiveValue:frame.origin.x forKey:@"xValue"];
    if (frame.origin.y != self.yValue)
        [self setPrimitiveValue:frame.origin.y forKey:@"yValue"];
    if (frame.size.width != self.widthValue)
        [self setPrimitiveValue:frame.size.width forKey:@"widthValue"];
    if (frame.size.height != self.heightValue)
        [self setPrimitiveValue:frame.size.height forKey:@"heightValue"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"frame"];
}
```

EDIT2:
Regarding your "fullName" problem... I would create a Person object with only firstName and lastName, and then a category

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person (FullName)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* fullName;
@end

//.m
#import "Person+FullName.h"

@implementation Person (FullName)
- (NSString*)fullName
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName];
}

- (void)setFullName:(NSString*)fullName
{
    NSArray *names = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"fullName"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"firstName"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"lastName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:names[0] forKey:@"firstName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:names[1] forKey:@"lastName"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"lastName"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"firstName"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"fullName"];
} 
@end
```

Comment: I think the correct/expected behavior is that if `fullName` get updated, observers of `fistName` and/or `lastName` should also be notified because the value did changed. But how to implement this behavior?

Comment: @xlc0212 if you call (as you did) `self.firstName` and `self.lastName` then the notifications get fired for you.. but then I don't understand your question....

Comment: if I set `firstName` then observer of `fullName` will be notified and same for `lastName`. This means the observer will get notified twice instead of one.

Comment: no..`fullName` is not notified. BTW: imho you should not code the full property in the "base" managedObject, but as a category, because it does not have a backing store variable.. it's just an operation... See my 2nd edit

Comment: what is the difference between having property on category or main implementation file?

Comment: The advice was related to the fact that you are deriving from NSManagedObject, and that Xcode can generate the classes for you. If you then modify your .m to add the implementations, every time you change the model and regenerate again the files you will overwrite them. With a category this will not happen. Further more.. I don't know if defining a property in the model creates a backing variable (and you don't want this for `fullName`

Comment: I am using mogenerator, which handle the code generation for me. Also create a property will not create backing variable if I implemented `-`-[setFullName]` and `-[fullName]`

Comment: I'm sure of this for NSObject subclasses, but not as sure for NSManagedObject subclasses, where the saving is handled by CoreData framework (you can test this. Put fullName as required property and implements your methods... then try to save the context)... Anyway.. this does not change the "notification" problems...